# How to change "We didn't find any matches" reply from a message extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a message extension using bot framework v3 (C#).
I'm having a requirement where if user enters only one alphabet then it should get message in message extension window as "please type at least 2 alpha bates".
When there are no search results it responded with "We didn't find any matches." so similar way i have to show a message. 
[image]
So how to achieve that.

Comment: Please include your request code sample which would be easier to answer.

Comment: Request is a standard POST api from Teams, with a Activity object.

Comment: If you are developing a new bot, do not do so with v3. It is being deprecated. V4 is the current and suggested version to use for new bots.

Comment: Its not a new bot, application is build in v3, please suggest on that

Comment: You are using [these](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams) extensions, correct? Can you show code sample as @md-farid-uddin-kiron suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I did not check in v3, but for the latest version (v4), this is how you can answer custom messages (in this case, when the search text comes empty):

```
if (searchText == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText.Value as string))
        {
            return new()
            {
                ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                {
                    Type = "message",
                    Text = "Type something..."
                }
            };
        }
```